# Why is Windows 7 announcing itself as an IPv6 router?

Tags: windows-7, router, ipv6

I have a 6in4 ipv6 connection from a linux box to a broker.  I use `gogoc` to establish the connection to the broker, and `radvd` to advertise the route to clients on the network.

All this appears to work, the problem is that I have a Windows 7 machine on the same network, and it is advertising itself as a ipv6 router.  Which it is not.

This is output from radvdump:

```
 #
# radvd configuration generated by radvdump 1.8.5
# based on Router Advertisement from [snip]:ea2
# received by interface eth0
#

interface eth0
{
        AdvSendAdvert on;
        # Note: {Min,Max}RtrAdvInterval cannot be obtained with radvdump
        AdvManagedFlag on;
        AdvOtherConfigFlag on;
        AdvReachableTime 0;
        AdvRetransTimer 0;
        AdvCurHopLimit 0;
        AdvDefaultLifetime 1800;
        AdvHomeAgentFlag off;
        AdvDefaultPreference medium;
        AdvSourceLLAddress on;
        AdvLinkMTU 1500;
}; # End of interface definition
#
# radvd configuration generated by radvdump 1.8.5
# based on Router Advertisement from [snip]:1121
# received by interface eth0
#

interface eth0
{
        AdvSendAdvert on;
        # Note: {Min,Max}RtrAdvInterval cannot be obtained with radvdump
        AdvManagedFlag off;
        AdvOtherConfigFlag off;
        AdvReachableTime 0;
        AdvRetransTimer 0;
        AdvCurHopLimit 64;
        AdvDefaultLifetime 1800;
        AdvHomeAgentFlag off;
        AdvDefaultPreference medium;
        AdvLinkMTU 1280;
        AdvSourceLLAddress on;

        prefix [snip]::/64
        {
                AdvValidLifetime 86400;
                AdvPreferredLifetime 14400;
                AdvOnLink on;
                AdvAutonomous on;
                AdvRouterAddr off;
        }; # End of prefix definition

}; # End of interface definition
```

And I end up with two routes:

```
$ ip -6 route
[snip]::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 86117sec
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
default via [snip]:ea2 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 1024  expires 1492sec
default via [snip]:1121 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 1024  expires 1506sec
```

The `ea2` route is to the Windows7 box.  It doesn't have a router installed, and doesn't have any tun/tap interfaces.  I can't see why it is doing this.

I could disable ipv6 on it, but I want it to be a client, not a router.

**Update**: The `IP Helper` service (`Provides tunnel connectivity using IPv6 transition technologies (6to4, ISATAP, Port Proxy, and Teredo), and IP-HTTPS. If this service is stopped, the computer will not have the enhanced connectivity benefits that these technologies offer.`) seems to be the culprit, as if it is stopped, I don't get the routes advertised.  So my question is now more specifically "why is IP Helper announcing routes?".

Answer (score 2):

- Run elevated `netsh` and go to `interface ipv6`.
- Check if `show route` lists any *published* routes.
- If it does, unpublish them with `set route ::/0 "Local Area Connection" publish=no`.

However, according to the `radvdump` output, your Windows box doesn't advertise any prefixes, so I don't see why would Linux add a default route through it.

- Use `show interface verbose` to list network interfaces; look for "Sends Router Advertisements" or similar values.
- Use `set interface "Local Area Connection forward=disable advertise=disable` to disable IPv6 forwarding and router advertisements.

Comment: No published routes.  Yeah I agree - no prefix, yet it is being accepted as a default. Weird behaviour.

Comment: @Paul: I added two commands I had forgot; they'll have to be adapted for Win7, but should completely disable the advertisements.

Comment: I am not familiar with the `show interface verbose` command - it doesn't work at any of the levels I tried.  I have found a way to stop the advertisements (I updated the question) - but my question is why is Windows doing this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried telling the Windows 7 machine where the default route lives or removing the bad from the router?  Unless you have ICS turned on it should be purely a client.